# Changing hidden inherited attributes in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, getter, conventions

I have a child class where I wish to overwrite an attribute from the parent class. The problem is this attribute is wrapped in a getter, and so to change it I have to access an underscored variable - hence breaking the "underscore => private" convention in Python. Minimal working example below.

```
class A:
    _x = "AxA"

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x


class B(A):
    _x = "BxB"  # seems non-pythonic


if __name__=="__main__":
    b = B()
    print(b.x)  # prints "BxB"
```

To be clear the above code works, it just doesn't seem very pythonic. Is there a better way to implement the above?

Comment: Why not override the method `x`?

Comment: you can overwrite the `x` property method

Comment: An underscore represents a protected member. Private members need to use two underscores. In other languages, protected members are allowed to be accessed and modified by subclasses.

Comment: @MechanicPig There's no concept of "protected" and "private" access in Python, unlike in C++ or Java. If a member name begins with a single underscore `_` it only _indicates the intent_ of the developer to show that this is not for "public consumption, but access like `MyClass._x` will still work. If a member name begins with a dunder `__`, this will actually cause Python to mangle the name and then `MyClass.__x` will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute you want to override is `x`, so override `x`:

```
class B(A):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return "BxB"
```

Comment: Does that not make the _x pointless? I was taught this was a relevant convention. However I did wonder myself why in class A it wasn't implemented as: 
`Class A:
  @property
  def x(self):
    return "AxA"`
without any reference to _x.